# Cross domain ajax request that returns xml using AngularJS

Tags: xml, ajax, angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to connect to the answerbase api using AngularJs. I got it to return the xml using jsonp but I get a format error. Unfortunately xml is the only format they will return.  I have attempted to use the xml2json library with no success.
This is what I have so far.

```
var url = "http://myAnswerBaseSite.com/api/getquestionslist.aspx?apikey=myKey&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url,
    {
        transformResponse: function (data) {
            var x2js = new X2JS();
            var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
            return json;
        }
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data.found);
    });
```

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same here. Unfortunately the jsonp function parses the content BEFORE the transform callback. So no, it's not possible.

You can only change the response to be a JSON or use another method.
(Well, you can also wrap the real API on your server and produce the same results in JSON format, building a mirror API service)

Have a nice day,

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the same service you are using, it is hard to pinpoint the issue. Are you using a public API?

I was able to get basic demo to work using `$http.get`. Take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tY4VKu?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var url = "data.xml";
  $http.get(url,{
    transformResponse: function (data) {
      var x2js = new X2JS();
      var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
      return json;
    }
  }).success(function (data) {
    $scope.foo = data.foo;
  });
});
```

Comment: This works if the xml is local. Since it is a cross domain request I get the "localhost is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin" error. So I need to use something like jsonp but for xml. Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to do a crossdomain request via localhost in Chrome, it will fail. You need to open Chrome with security disabled (open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security). Otherwise, you need to make sure the service has been properly configured for CORS or you can continue down the JSONP route. I will attempt to get JSONP working in the demo.

Comment: I second the CORS comment.

Comment: @moderndegree- Thanks, I dont think disabling it in chrome is an option, I need it to work for everyone. There isn't much documentation on the API but I am sending an email to the support team to ask about the CORS. I am going to take a guess and say that its probably not configured for CORS though. Thanks,

Comment: well... in that case, I would propose creating a proxy service on your own server and then transform the response server-side.